# if condition not working in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement

I am working on  mobile application with nodejs and mongo db for server side functionality.

I have implemented a custom header to be sent in every request and I have following function to check header values.

Here is my CODE :

```
 /**
     * 
     * Check Request headers
     * @param : headers 
     * @returns : boolean
     * 
     * */
    function checkHeaders(data) {
        var customHeader = JSON.stringify(data.appsecret).valueOf().trim();
        var contentTypeHeader = JSON.stringify(data["content-type"]).valueOf().trim();
        if (contentTypeHeader === "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" && customHeader === "xxxxx") {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Here I always get 0 as the response and I have checked the values of all 3 variables i.e. 
1. data, 
2. customHeader ,
3. contentTypeHeader 
are received correct. but the values in if condition are not matched and I always get " 0 " as the result.

Any suggestion would be a great help!

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: check what is the type of `customHeader` and `contentTypeHeader` and also check the values of both.

Comment: it's a string. notice the JSON.stringify()

Comment: @Todd: yes, I am getting all the values in the respective variables but still i am not able to compare the values with another string

Comment: valueOf() returns the **primitive** value of a string, so `customHeader` == "xxxxx" evals to false

Comment: can you `console.log("type: ", JSON.stringify(data["content-type"]), "custom: ", JSON.stringify(data.appsecret, null, 4))`. is what you've done to check the values? I'm trying to help, friend.

Comment: Your issue resolved?

Comment: @Todd: I have not marked your answer negative! I have logged all the variables and they are correctly received. but still not able to compare them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The data parameter itself is an object and dose not need the stringify operation.

here is the updated code which works fine
CODE :

```
/**
     * 
     * Check Request headers
     * @param : headers 
     * @returns : boolean
     * 
     * */
    function checkHeaders(data) {
     if (data['content-type'] === "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" && data.appsecret === "xxxxx") {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

## edit

ok, so the REAL problem is that you're using `.valueOf` after `JSON.stringify`, which returns the primitive value of a string, which would not be equal to the strings in your conditional; try removing the `str.valueOf()` and just leave the `.trim()` if needed.

try this, and notice the `==` where `===` were:

```
return contentTypeHeader == "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" && customHeader == "xxxxx";
```

instead of this:

```
    if (contentTypeHeader === "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" && customHeader === "xxxxx") {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I have tried the above code, still the result is same